# MongoDB query does not find documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat, nosql

My query does not find documents in my MongoDB collection

This is example object in the database (notice that position.x and position.y are Longs in Salat)

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("50e85039e4b0f225b98b8b34"),
  "worldSlug": "test",
  "position": {
    "x": {
      "floatApprox": 3
    },
    "y": {
      "floatApprox": 3
    }
  },
  "type": "village",
  "owner": "mati",
  "health": {
    "got": 500,
    "total": 500
  }
}
```

This is my query

```
{
  "worldSlug": "test",
  "position": {
    "x": {
     "$gt": -31,
     "$lt": 29
    },
    "y": {
      "$gt": -27,
      "$lt": 33
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to query on embedded fields.  Use a query object like this instead:

```
{
  "worldSlug": "test",
  "position.x": {
     "$gt": -31,
     "$lt": 29
  },
  "position.y": {
      "$gt": -27,
      "$lt": 33
  }
}
```

Comment: Nearly ok. The solution was that dot notation. `floatApprox` property was shown only in shell because it does not support Long type